# how to remove hashtag in ie 8 while using history.js plugin

Tags: javascript, history.js

I've built a site that uses the History.js plugin to navigate from page to page with AJAX and update the URL accordingly. All works well except in IE; when you refresh the page it essentially loads the content from the first page you came to, not the current pages content. In "decent" browsers it doesn't load the content from any page, it just loads the entire page for that URL, which is what I IE should do.

I'm thinking it doesn't understand what to do with the hash. If you visit 
for example

example.com/something 
 it works fine, but when you visit example.com/#something (with the hash) it comes.

I've attempted to redirect the page if it detects a # in the pathname, but there is no way of detecting this as window.location.pathname and History.getHash() returns the path without any hash.

Any suggestions? I've seen a few websites using this plugin that have the same problem, and similar issues on here, but no solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash
```

should return the hash in your console.log (caveat - if you're testing for IE8, you should be able to grab the hash with the above, but you'll have trouble reading the object sin